# MS Access Copying value from a form into another form text box

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

Here's my problem: I have the below code which copies the employee username from FormB and puts it in FrmEmployee when i click on a record in FormB (which is opened through a cmd button on FrmEmployee and lists all employees in the company and their shift pattern).

```vba
Private Sub Form_Click()
Forms!FrmEmployeee.Form.Username = Me.Username
End Sub
```

This works but it will only set the current username field to what is selected on FormB. FormB is in a datasheet view and will hold multiple values for the employee username. So what I want to do is expand the above code somehow so it takes me to the next record on FrmEmployee which means when i select another user from FormB this value will be copied into the next Username record, allowing me to build a list of employees.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you need actually is to store multiple line/items from your FORM B.

So my suggestion is changing your textbox on FrmEmployee into a ListBox. So everytime you out the cursor on the active record, it add the record into the listbox